# Split a large text file

Tags: windows, macos, text-editing

I have a large text file grouped with separate headers that I need to split into separate files.

For instance the file has headers like this:

```
--Heading 1--
some text
text

--Heading 2--
more text etc

--Heading 3--
asdf text
```

I need to split the large file into text files based on their headers.

So for the example, there would be a 3 file output.

Heading 1.txt:

```
--Heading 1--
some text
text
```

Heading 2.txt:

```
--Heading 2--
more text etc
```

Heading 3.txt:

```
--Heading 3--
asdf text
```

Does anyone know of a windows or max app/script that can do this?

Or maybe give instructions on how to write something like this in a programming language. I don't know python or java but maybe this is the time to learn. :)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the simplest answer, hopefully someone will come up with something neater. I put together a little script which will do this that should work on the Mac.

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMFILES=`grep '^--.*--' $1 | wc -l`
NUMFILES=$(($NUMFILES - 2))
csplit -k $1 '%^--.*--$%' '/^--.*--$/' "{$NUMFILES}" 
for file in `ls xx*`
do
        mv $file "`head -n1 $file | sed -e 's/--\(.*\)--/\1.txt/'`"
done
```

This works using `csplit` to chop up the file. The fourth line basically says ignore everything before the first header line and then split up the headers after that. lines 2-3 work out how many times csplit has to split up the file.

`csplit` names its output files xx followed by a 2 digit number. The last 4 lines rename all these files to whatever is in the header line with the `--` removed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "one liner" 8-]. It's similar to what Martin has down.
This will work on your Mac. Just open up the "Terminal" app and navigate to the directory containing `myfile.txt`

```
split -p '--.*--' myfile.txt FILE && for file in FILE*; do mv $file "$(head -1 $file | sed 's/--//g')".txt; done
```

PS. Make sure there are no files in the directory that are named FILE*. ie, make sure `ls FILE*` shows nothing.